# Земена файла при обновлении поля ImageField В модели Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, файлы

Есть модель

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    avatar = models.ImageField('Аватар', upload_to='avatars')
```

Загружаем аватар первый раз:

```
img = ImageModel(name=name)
img.avatar.save(some_file_name, ContentFile(img_file))
img.save()
```

Получаем:

> /name
>   img_file.bmp

Подгружает второй раз в ту же модель.

```
img.avatar.save(some_file_name, ContentFile(img_file))
img.save()
```

Получаем:

> /name
>   img_file.bmp
>   img_file_NlkiAsd.bmp

Еще раз.
Получаем:

> /name
>   img_file.bmp
>   img_file_NlkiAsd.bmp
>   img_file_zlJUmDx.bmp

Помогите накодить чтоб файлы не множились, а сохранялись под тем же именем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class ReplacingFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name

class ImageModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    avatar = models.ImageField('Аватар', upload_to='avatars', storage=ReplacingFileStorage())
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. подскажите а не нужно ли вы зывать метот get_available_name() родительского класса?

Comment: когда пытаюсь вызвать super().get_available_name(self, name, max_length=max_length). пишет  get_available_name() got multiple values for argument 'max_length'

Comment: В данном случае не нужно.